# Add extension .csv to file created with Views Data Export

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

To export user data into a csv I've setup a view display of type **data export** succesfully. 
I've setup a path "admin/people/export" and when visiting it will return a file. 
The file is a csv file but it's created without the extension .csv.

Is there a way to create this file with this extension?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the view settings click on *Format: CSV File > Settings*

> [image: screenshot]

In the dialog box that appear, be sure that *Provide as file* is selected. In the *Filename* field that appears when that option is selected, leave the default value (*%view.csv*).

> [image: screenshot]

*%view*, which adds the view machine name to the filename, is only one of the available replacement tokens. As visible in the screenshot, the other ones are:

- %display
- %exposed
- %timestamp-full
- %timestamp-yy
- %timestamp-yyyy
- %timestamp-mm
- %timestamp-mmm
- %timestamp-dd
- %timestamp-ddd
- %timestamp-hh
- %timestamp-ii
- %timestamp-ss